# Why is an apostrophe appearing as &#x27; in Ruby on Rails and is this a sign of a security issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, form-helpers

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm using a form_helper to create and update records. In the form below, I'm collecting information to save data for maps that users can create. The :name field is the name that user gives to a map. It's saved to a MySQL table into a field that is varchar(255).

If I name a map "John's Map", it appears in both the database and in the view as

```
    John&#x27;s Map
```

How can I prevent this from happening, and is my code susceptible to SQL injection with this approach?

I've seen some responses related to Python and PHP, but I wasn't sure about Rails. I'm using Virtualmin to create tables, so any responses that let me address the issue within Virtualmin would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**From View**

```
    <% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>

    <% if params[:newsavedmap_id] %>
<%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=> @newsavedmap.name }%></p>
    <% else %>
<%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=>"New Map"}%></p>
    <% end %>
```

**Database Table Details**

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `newsavedmaps`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `newsavedmaps` (
    FIELDSAREALLLISTEDHERE
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=159 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Other tables in the database display the apostrophe. For example, I have another form that looks like the below, and when a user enters a name with an apostrophe, the apostrophe appears as an apostrophe in the table.

```
    <form id="createitem" action="/saveditems" method="post">
    <label for="saveditem_name">Item Title</label>
    <%= text_field :saveditem, :name %>
```

That table's structure:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `saveditems`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `saveditems` (
    FIELDSAREALLLISTEDHERE
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8418 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

**Edit 1**

I used ALTER TABLE newsavedmaps CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1; and my newsavedmaps table now looks like this:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `newsavedmaps`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `newsavedmaps` (
    FIELDS ALL LISTED HERE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=248 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

The apostrophes now appear correctly in the database, but they still show up in the view as strange characters. Any ideas? Could this have anything to do with this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9108

Comment: Where are you seeing the apostrophe appear as &#x27? When you look at the database? The &#27; is the ASCII character encoding it may be that the encoding for your database is utf8, so the encoding is appearing instead of the apostrophe

Comment: Thanks, John. Question has been updated with details.

Comment: I used this command in Webmin's execute SQL field: `ALTER TABLE newsavedmaps CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1;` and when I open the mysql database in Notepad, it tells me `) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=354 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;` which looks correct. The database also has the correct appearance "John's Map". However, the ASCII character encoding is still appearing when I edit the map in the view. Why is this still happening?