# Where can I find the output_safety.rb and how can I edit it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm working on a Rails 2.3X website, and I am looking in my FTP system for this file:

activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb

However, it doesn't seem to be showing up in the web code. How can I get to the file and edit it for my website?

I'm trying to update this file because apostrophes that appear in my field form are showing up as

```
    &#x27;
```

and I believe it's related to an issue with the version of Rails. More details are here https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/88331c575bf5a7ef2451e008881641322ee562b4

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to update this file? I'm new to Rails, and my plan was to open the file, edit it in Notepad++, and then overwrite the existing file. I appreciate any help you can offer.

**View in Rails**

```
<label id="savedmap_name_label" for="savemap_name">Map Title</label>

<% if params[:newsavedmap_id] %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=> @newsavedmap.name }%></p>
<% else %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=>"New Map"}%></p>
<% end %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never try to update the Framework files, may I know what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Sure. Please see here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500875/why-is-an-apostrophe-appearing-as-x27-in-ruby-on-rails-and-is-this-a-sign-of I believe the cause of this issue is the version of Rails I'm running, and the link I provided shows a fix to that file may help with the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use "h" function like this:- <%=h @map.title%>

Comment: How would I do that with the above view code? And what will it do?

Comment: In your erb file do that.

Comment: I tried this using the code above `<%=h f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=> @newsavedmap.name }%>` but it didn't change anything. Is that what you mean?

Comment: <%=f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=> @newsavedmap.name.html_safe }%>

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks a ton. I gave you the solution because it solved the problem I was having, but it'd still be good to know where can I find the output_safety.rb.